# Angularjs Bootstrap Select Creates Duplicate Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

So I am using bootstrap datepicker from https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select and it works fine when I am using desktop browser. I also use **AngularJS**.

The code is:

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="spec in specs">
    <label class="control-label">{{spec.SpecName}}</label>
    <select ng-change="getBuyPrice(false)" class="form-control selectpicker" 
            ng-model="selectedSpec[$index]" data-live-search="true">
        <option value="">-- Select {{spec.SpecName}} --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="value in spec.Values" value="{{value.ID}}">
          {{value.Value}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It looks find on the desktop browser and it is working as expected. There is no bug found in it. 
[image: Desktop Browser]

But then when I use my mobile and browse it, it shows duplicate `select picker` on mobile browser.

[image: On Mobile]

The Spec (Color) got repeated twice on mobile browser, I have tried to use different browser but the result is the same. I also tried to use chrome debugger (on desktop) and click `toggle device toolbar` it works fine on the debugger.

Please help

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1700

Answer (score 0):

So this is a head banging problem. I tried to inspect my phone with Chrome remote debugging tools. I found that:

```
$('select.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

is the one causing the problem. I do not know why its working on Desktop but not in mobile. It is still a mystery. However changing the class name from `selectpicker` to something else solves the problem. In my case I just changed it into `selectsearch`.

```
$('select.selectsearch').selectpicker('refresh');
```

I hope this helps anyone who has the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2738) in selectpicker-1.14.0-beta3.  I'm using bootstrap 5 which requires beta3 and I see duplication of options on desktop. There is a suggested solution in the discussion of the issue, but that suggestion didn't work for me.  I will have to stop calling refresh until the bug is fixed.